# What is a DOPE bike?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

On the internet I came across this sentence:

> That’s a [DOPE](http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=utoHlFX3eK8) bike!

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dope) it has a positive meaning when used as an adjective.

Black slang: very good.

I’m not sure whether I’ve got the correct meaning, which is why I nicely ask that you help me understand if there is a positive or a negative meaning.

Comment: The meaning you found seems to fit fine :) The remark is positive :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It is also worth highlighting the usage note ("black slang") from your source. This is an idiom that is unlikely to be heard from anyone outside certain subcultures—namely African-American (and various young people influenced by it).

Comment: In my experience, *dope* in this sense is pretty common mainstream slang among US speakers born after the mid-80s or so.  It's by no means limited to African-American subcultures anymore.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I stand corrected. Here (Australia) it's very sharply limited to young people who adopt other aspects of African-American culture--hip-hop and whatnot.